# Concatenating 2 columns in sql and applying like operation on the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(SG.firstname +' ', SG.lastName) AS  'Name', 
    SG.entityId 'ID',
    dbo.GetTitleDescriptionByEntityID(SG.entityId) 'Title',
    CASE ISNULL(EC.address2, '') 
      WHEN '' THEN EC.address1 
      ELSE EC.address1 +', ' + EC.address2
    END +', ' + EC.city + ', ' + LDState.ItemName + ', ' + EC.zip 'Address',
    CR.clinicalRate
FROM 
    StaffGeneral SG WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN 
    LookupDetails LD WITH (NOLOCK) ON SG.employeeStatus = LD.lookupDetailsId AND LD.ItemAbbreviation = 'SCSSC'
JOIN
    othersRating or1 WITH (nolock) ON SG.entityId = or1.entityId AND dateRated = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(dateRated) FROM OthersRating r1 WITH (nolock) WHERE r1.entityid = SG.entityId)       
JOIN 
    LookupDetails LDRating with (nolock) ON or1.rating = LDRating.lookupDetailsId AND LDRating.ItemAbbreviation NOT IN ('RTNP', 'RTDNU', 'RTPENDING', 'RTDELETE', 'RTTERMI')    
JOIN 
    EntityContacts EC with (nolock) ON SG.entityId = EC.entityId AND (eC.contactId = 'General' or EC.contactId = 'General1') AND EC.deleted = 0
JOIN 
    LookupDetails LDState WITH (NOLOCK) ON EC.state = LDState.lookupDetailsId
JOIN 
    ContractorRate CR ON SG.entityId = CR.entityId AND CR.deleted = 0
WHERE 
    SG.isActive = 0 AND SG.deleted = 0
    AND ((SG.entityId = @subContractorID) OR (@subContractorID IS null))
    AND ((@subContractorName IS NULL) OR ((EC.firstName + ' ' + EC.lastName) LIKE @subContractorName + '%'))
```

In the above query I wanted to concat the first and last name with space and query it against the input to the stored procedure `@subcontractorname`.

When the `subcontractorname` is null that is fine but I am not able to get results when it jumps to Or clause .

Tried the SQL Server Profiler but does not show anything how the query is formed

I tried executing the SQL by putting the whole SQL in a var but I am hitting the problem of `varchar(max)`.

Please advise

Comment: Does it work when you just select from EC with the condition by itself? Did you mean `'%' + @subContractor + '%'`? That name matching doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: The Concatination works in the line (  SELECT CONCAT(SG.firstname +' ', SG.lastName) AS  'Name'). but when trying to query  against it does not work..... Is there a way I can see how this query is formed when executing the  stored prod -shawnt00

Comment: I'm not questioning the contenation. It's the other side of the `LIKE` that looks potentially wrong to me. You said you tried Profiler and yes, it would let you see queries coming through. But it doesn't let you see anything happened at the level of individual rows of data. The easiest thing to do is to isolate a simple `SELECT` on one table with the one condition in question.

Comment: select * from EntityContacts EC where EC.firstName + ' ' + EC.lastName LIKE @subContractorName + '%' -- does this return what you expect?

Comment: yes the select returns what I am expecting and that is the first thing i have checked while writing the select...

Comment: It sounds like it should work. So it you pass 'BOB' then you expect to get back 'BOB TAYLOR', 'BOBBY SMITH', etc...? What's a typical values of @subContractorName going to look like?